# FFMpeg stream to FFServer from Back Camera

Tags: camera, linux, command-line, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm looking for a way to stream my camera video from my Android phone to an FFServer, like I would with FFMpeg from the command line in Linux:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 http://IP:8090/cam1.ffm
```

This command works perfect from any Ubuntu machine, of course. I'm looking to be able to do both audio and video from my Android to my FFserver.

I tried installing [FFmpeg 4 Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android). It installs fine, starts and binds, but it won't stream. No error message or anything passing it this param:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/graphics/fb0 http://IP:8090/cam1.ffm
```

Not sure if it's just that program or what since there is no error message at all. Or is there another software that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Some device manufacturers dont use /graphics/fb0 to access camera due to different camera drivers. My help to you is going on a native NDK application to do that. Look in here http://javacv.googlecode.com or https://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/. Regards